# How do I avoid the replacement of the '^?' character during a search and replace operation in Microsoft Word?

Tags: search, replace, ms-word

Recently, I found that the search and replace function in Microsoft Word is very convenient. I would like to ask you to suggest a manual. As well as solving a specific situation. In the search bar, I enter these characters "^?^p". In the replacement line "^? ". The program says that replacement with "^p" is impossible, which is logical. But then how does the character "^?" appear in the search bar? highlight so that the program does not replace it ?
In other words, I want to understand whether it is possible in the program, when replacing, not to allow the replacement of specific characters

This is a small problem, and I know quite a bit about the many features of Microsoft Word.

Example:
There are paragraphs throughout the text that are incorrectly placed. I need to fix it, but manually hundreds of paragraphs on hundreds of pages is a long time to do it. For example.
"In other words, I want to understand
whether it is possible in the program, when replacing, not to allow the replacement of specific characters."
Search: ^?^p
Replace: "whitespace"
The error is that the letter (^?) is also subject to replacement. If you add (^?) to the replacement, then microsoft word will say that it is impossible to replace it with a random letter.

Comment: The problem scenario is too poorly described. Not sure what exactly you're trying to do. Sorry.

Comment: *In other words, I want to understand whether it is possible in the program, when replacing, not to allow the replacement of specific characters* Yes it's, with VBA and RegEx（regular expression). Just what are your specific needs and can you give an example to illustrate them?

Comment: *There are paragraphs throughout the text that are incorrectly placed. I need to fix it,* This is why the need to use VBA, but also the value of the existence of VBA ah. It's also why I will learn VBA independently (I study Chinese, not IT staff) So what do you say? Specify the conditions you want to avoid error replacement, and I'll try to write a piece of code for you to play with. *For example. "In other words, I want to understand whether it is possible in the program, when replacing, not to allow the replacement of specific characters."* That's the basic facility, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

> There are paragraphs throughout the text that are incorrectly placed. I need to fix it, ... when replacing, not to allow the replacement of specific characters." Search: ^?^p Replace: "whitespace" The error is that the letter (^?) is also subject to replacement.

I'd just like to use your example to write this code for you to try:

```vb
Sub FixIncorrectlyParagraphs_how_do_i_avoid_the_replacement_of_the_character_during_a_search_and_replace()
    Dim rng As Range, d As Document, a As Range, b As Range, ur As UndoRecord
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = d.Content
    If InStr(rng.Text, Chr(13)) = 1 Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Characters.Count < 3 Then Exit Sub
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "FixIncorrectlyParagraphs_how_do_i_avoid_the_replacement_of_the_character_during_a_search_and_replace"
    With rng.Find
        .Text = "^p"
        Do While .Execute(, , , , , , True, wdFindStop)
            If rng.Next Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Set a = rng.Previous.Characters(rng.Previous.Characters.Count)
            Set b = rng.Next.Characters(1)
            If IsAlphabet(a) And IsAlphabet(b) Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            ElseIf IsAlphabet(a) And VBA.IsNumeric(b) Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            ElseIf IsAlphabet(b) And VBA.IsNumeric(a) Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            ElseIf VBA.IsNumeric(a) And VBA.IsNumeric(b) Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            ElseIf a = " " And VBA.IsNumeric(b) Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            ElseIf b = " " And VBA.IsNumeric(a) Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            ElseIf a = " " And IsAlphabet(b) Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            ElseIf b = " " And IsAlphabet(a) Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            End If
            rng.SetRange rng.End, d.Content.End
        Loop
    End With
    ur.EndCustomRecord
    Exit Sub
    
fixIncorrectlyParagraph:
    rng.Text = vbNullString
    Return
End Sub
Function IsAlphabet(a As Range) As Boolean
    IsAlphabet = a Like "[A-Za-z]"
End Function
```

## Rewrite code with [Type statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-statement)

```vb
Type CharPorp
     IsAlphabet As Boolean
     IsNumeric As Boolean
     IsSpace As Boolean
End Type
Rem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76385329/how-do-i-avoid-the-replacement-of-the-character-during-a-search-and-replace
Sub FixIncorrectlyParagraphs_how_do_i_avoid_the_replacement_of_the_character_during_a_search_and_replace()
    Dim rng As Range, d As Document, a As Range, b As Range, ur As UndoRecord, ta As CharPorp, tb As CharPorp
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = d.Content
    If InStr(rng.Text, Chr(13)) = 1 Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Characters.Count < 3 Then Exit Sub
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "FixIncorrectlyParagraphs_how_do_i_avoid_the_replacement_of_the_character_during_a_search_and_replace"

    With rng.Find
        .Text = "^p"
        Do While .Execute(, , , , , , True, wdFindStop)
            If rng.Next Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Set a = rng.Previous.Characters(rng.Previous.Characters.Count)
            Set b = rng.Next.Characters(1)
            With ta
                .IsNumeric = VBA.IsNumeric(a)
                .IsAlphabet = IsAlphabet(a)
                .IsSpace = a = " "
            End With
            With tb
                .IsNumeric = VBA.IsNumeric(b)
                .IsAlphabet = IsAlphabet(b)
                .IsSpace = b = " "
            End With
            
            If ta.IsAlphabet And tb.IsAlphabet Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            ElseIf ta.IsAlphabet And tb.IsNumeric Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            ElseIf tb.IsAlphabet And ta.IsNumeric Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            ElseIf ta.IsNumeric And tb.IsNumeric Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            ElseIf ta.IsSpace And tb.IsNumeric Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            ElseIf tb.IsSpace And ta.IsNumeric Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            ElseIf ta.IsSpace And tb.IsAlphabet Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            ElseIf tb.IsSpace And ta.IsAlphabet Then
                GoSub fixIncorrectlyParagraph
            End If
            rng.SetRange rng.End, d.Content.End
        Loop
    End With
    ur.EndCustomRecord
    Exit Sub
    
fixIncorrectlyParagraph:
    rng.Text = vbNullString
    Return
End Sub
Function IsAlphabet(a As Range) As Boolean
    IsAlphabet = a Like "[A-Za-z]"
End Function
```

[image]

If you don't know how to run the macro, I can share a .docm or .dotm file for you to test. Just open that file and it will run this program to show you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried the macro, it works, but for some reason it forgets to add a space after use.

Comment: @OlgerdOrikj What's the meaning of "but for some reason it forgets to add a space after use. "* ? You did not response your original request and opened a new one? You were only asking if code could do it. As for the other details, I think they are other questions. If *it works* indeed, then what you want to know before is already answered you.